# Link rule data to master data table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, select

```
create table CIT_ADMIN.OBJECT_DETAIL_MASTER (
  RULE_ID   VARCHAR(10), 
  ATTR_1   VARCHAR(50), 
  ATTR_2   VARCHAR(50), 
  ATTR_3   VARCHAR(50), 
  CREATED_DATE    DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE)

create table CIT_ADMIN.PRIORITY_RULE_FACTORY (
  RULE_ID   VARCHAR(10), 
  RULE_DESC VARCHAR(10), 
  RULE_1   VARCHAR(50), 
  RULE_2   VARCHAR(50), 
  RULE_3   VARCHAR(50), 
  CREATED_DATE    DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE)

insert into CIT_ADMIN.PRIORITY_RULE_FACTORY
       (RULE_ID, RULE_DESC,  RULE_1,         RULE_2,          RULE_3)
values ('1',     'POSITION', 'ODS_KEY',      'NOTIONAL',      'SIK')

insert into CIT_ADMIN.PRIORITY_RULE_FACTORY
       (RULE_ID, RULE_DESC,  RULE_1,         RULE_2,          RULE_3)
values ('2',     'CLIENT',   'UCN',          'AGREEMENT_ID',  'FACILITY_ID')

insert into CIT_ADMIN.PRIORITY_RULE_FACTORY
       (RULE_ID, RULE_DESC,  RULE_1,         RULE_2,          RULE_3)
values ('3',     'NETTING',  'AGREEMENT_ID', 'AGREEMENT_AMT', 'MATURITY')

insert into CIT_ADMIN.OBJECT_DETAIL_MASTER
       (RULE_ID, ATTR_1, ATTR_2, ATTR_3)
values ('1',     '123',  '1000', '600')

insert into CIT_ADMIN.OBJECT_DETAIL_MASTER
       (RULE_ID, ATTR_1, ATTR_2, ATTR_3)
values ('2',     '456',  '2000', '500')

insert into CIT_ADMIN.OBJECT_DETAIL_MASTER
       (RULE_ID, ATTR_1, ATTR_2, ATTR_3)
values ('3',     '789',  '3000', '400')
```

These are my tables. Rule id is foreign key in master table, also the primary key in rule factory table. I tried writing query that can link the rule with the data.

```
**Like:**
WITH ATTR AS (SELECT * FROM CIT_ADMIN.PRIORITY_RULE_FACTORY WHERE RULE_DESC = 'POSITION')

SELECT ATTR_2 FROM CIT_ADMIN.OBJECT_DETAIL_MASTER a
WHERE RULE_ID in (SELECT ATTR.RULE_ID FROM attr) 
AND ATTR_1 = '123'
```

If I know position and ods_key I want Notional. This query fetched me that but the problem is i dont know the position of those attributes. Can you guys please give me some pointers to move ahead.!!!

Regards.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the "position" of the attributes.  Please edit your question and explain further. Thanks.  (And BTW, here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa622/1) containing the schema and query).

Comment: @Bob : All i meant was, i will have information in the form of rules, as described in the rule table. When i say rule 1, it means position, as defined in rule description. and rule_1, rule_2, rule_3 are the attributes of position object, like - ods_key, notional, etc... whose values are present in master table. So, when i say it is a position object rule_id becomes 1. So for this type of object i need the notional value when ods_key = 123

Comment: So i need something that can map the column name of data(in this case Notional) from rule table, then read the corresponding value of column from master table.

Comment: I'm with Bob here, I don't 100% understand what you're after; there are no column names to map. Could you provide your expected output as well?

Comment: The way to connect two tables are via the rule_id. The master table is basically a table to hold unstructured data. Another way to visualize it is to consider: ATTR_1 maps to rule_1, ATTR_2 maps to rule_2, and similarly for others. In this way I dont have to create one master table with multiple columns where lot of columns are null.

Comment: @Ben : I am also flexible to change the table design. But my requirement is to have minimum number of table to represent and query multiple non overlapping data objects like: position, client, netting...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a pretty ropey design.  I mean, there must be something wrong with a model when the notoriously poor EAV pattern appears like a sensible alternative.

Anyway, here is a function which resolves the task in hand: I suggest a function simply because Rules Engines are tricky beasts, and encapsulation will serve you well when it comes to revising your functionality.

```
create or replace function eval_rule
    ( p_rule_id in priority_rule_factory.rule_id%type
      , p_rule in priority_rule_factory.rule_1%type )
     return object_detail_master.attr_1%type
is
    return_value object_detail_master.attr_1%type;
begin

     select case 
            when prf.rule_1 = p_rule then odm.attr_1
            when prf.rule_2 = p_rule then odm.attr_2
            when prf.rule_3 = p_rule then odm.attr_3
            end
    into return_value
    from priority_rule_factory prf
         join object_detail_master odm
            on prf.rule_id = odm.rule_id
    where prf.rule_id = p_rule_id;        

    return return_value;
end eval_rule;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to work with if you normalize the "rules" and "attributes" - create a table which holds a single attribute name (e.g. 'ODS_KEY', 'NOTIONAL', etc) and the value which goes with it (e.g. 123, 1000, etc) and relate this to a rule (e.g. 'POSITION', 'CLIENT', 'NETTING', etc).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: My requirement is more on the Meta-Data driven side. So I am thinking of using a columnar DB instead. Still appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.